# boost::variant gettor-visitor: saving returned references

Tags: c++, boost, visitor-pattern, boost-variant

I have tried to write a vistor for `boost::variant` that takes a parameter pack of types and generates an `operator()` for each type. While the correct functions get called, I still get an error when trying to save the get-ed object from the visitor in a variable.

My Visitor is this:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class GenericGettorSpecialization
{
public:
    const T& operator()(T& t)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
        return t;
    }
};

template <class...>
class GenericGettorSpecializationDriver;

template <>
class GenericGettorSpecializationDriver<>
{
public:
    struct dummy
    {
    };
    const dummy& operator()(const dummy&);
};

template <class Head, class... Tail>
class GenericGettorSpecializationDriver<Head, Tail...>
  : protected GenericGettorSpecializationDriver<Tail...>,
    protected GenericGettorSpecialization<Head>
{
public:
    using GenericGettorSpecializationDriver<Tail...>::operator();
    using GenericGettorSpecialization<Head>::operator();
};

template <class Head, class... Tail>
struct GenericGettor
  : boost::static_visitor<>,
    protected GenericGettorSpecializationDriver<Head, Tail...>
{
public:
    using GenericGettorSpecializationDriver<Head, Tail...>::operator();
};
```

As you can see for debug purposes in put `std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";` in the call operator.

Now I tested it like this:

```
int
main()
{
    boost::variant<std::string, int, double> v;
    GenericGettor<std::string, int, double>  g;

    v = "some string";
    boost::apply_visitor(g, v); // prints "NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE"

    v = 10;
    boost::apply_visitor(g, v); // prints "i"

    v = 7.3;
    boost::apply_visitor(g, v); // prints "d"

    auto x = boost::apply_visitor(g, v); // throws compile time error  "error: variable has incomplete type 'void'"
}
```

Apparently `boost::apply_vistor` returns `void`, but then how do I get the references out of the `variant`?

Comment: Every variable must have a definite type at compile-time. A variant's content at an arbitrary point of execution is not known until runtime. If you want to extract an object from a variant (and get an exception if the types don't match at runtime), use [`boost::get`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/get_idp74804384.html).

Comment: But what if I don't know the type the variant currently holds? On the boost documentation the visitor comes into play for this situation, but confusingly they don't use the visitor to get anything but rather manipulate the value in the variant: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. The visitor contains one overload per possible type and `apply_visitor` calls the correct one. From then on, you know the static type inside the overload -- but it can't bubble back up. If you want to retrieve a specific static type, you need `get`. How you use these two tools to implement your program depends on what you wish to do with them.

Comment: Well, what I originally wanted to achieve was to have a gettor object `gettor`  that receives as template arguments the same types as the variant it is supposed to deal with. Then upon passing in a variant of that type to some function `get_value` like `gettor.get_value(variant_instance)` it would return the value held by the variant. But I got stuck at the "bubbling up" step.

Comment: Well, sadly that syntax is impossible, because `get_value`'s return type cannot be determined at compile-time. You could return another type-erased object such as `boost::any` or a polymorphic instance, but you won't be able to retrieve the contained type statically.

Answer (score 0):

Such a getter already exists: [boost::get<> function template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/get_idp1003723808.html).

However, keep in mind that the variant contents is set at *run-time*, so it is absolutely impossible to know it at *compile-time*.

That's why you should tell `get` function template what type you want it to return - and if the variant does not contain it at that point of time, it will throw exception.

Alternatively, you could use [`variant::which()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#idp1003211296-bb) member function, which returns an index of the current type - which is also a run-time value.